# optimize the SQL query to reduce the number of time I have to runit

Tags: sql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have a below query which I want to optimize, right now I have to change the year each time to get the data for multiple years. I want a query which would show me the data for all the year. I am trying to find the customers which are in the SL_NEWCUST2015HTRETCUST table and see if the same customers have made purchases in 2016, 2017, 2018 and 2019 by joining it to the main transactions_detail table. for this I have to change the year every time to see if they have made purchases in each year:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT INDIVIDUAL_ID),
CASE WHEN COUNT_OF_TRANSACTIONS = 1 THEN '1'
WHEN COUNT_OF_TRANSACTIONS = 2 THEN '2'
WHEN COUNT_OF_TRANSACTIONS = 3 THEN '3'
WHEN COUNT_OF_TRANSACTIONS = 4 THEN '4'
WHEN COUNT_OF_TRANSACTIONS  >= 5 THEN '5+' END AS TXN_TYPE,
SUM(spend), 
SUM( COUNT_OF_TRANSACTIONS)

FROM (select distinct a.individual_id, count(distinct transaction_number) as COUNT_OF_TRANSACTIONS, sum(a.dollar_value_us) as spend from dm_owner.transaction_detail_mv a join SL_NEWCUST2015HTRETCUST b on a.individual_id = b.individual_id
where brand_org_code = 'HT'
and is_merch = 1
and LINE_ITEM_AMT_TYPE_CD = 'S'
and CURRENCY_CODE = 'USD'
and a.individual_id is not null
and COUNT_OF_TRANSACTIONS >= 5
and TYPE_OF_CUSTOMER = 'Returning Customers'
and trunc(txn_date) between '01-JAN-16' AND '31-DEC-16'  ---- I have to change the years here everytime I run the query
group by a.individual_id)

GROUP BY CASE WHEN COUNT_OF_TRANSACTIONS = 1 THEN '1'
WHEN COUNT_OF_TRANSACTIONS = 2 THEN '2'
WHEN COUNT_OF_TRANSACTIONS = 3 THEN '3'
WHEN COUNT_OF_TRANSACTIONS = 4 THEN '4'
WHEN COUNT_OF_TRANSACTIONS  >= 5 THEN '5+' END
ORDER BY 1 ASC;
```

so if I want the data from 2016 to 2019 I have to run the query 4 time. Is there a way to just run it once and it gives me all the data at once. Below is the screenshot of the format I copy paste the data for each year:

[format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O5NZW.png)

Answer (score 0):

By trunc(txn_date,'YYYY') each of the trasnaction date would be bucketed to the start of year.

So if you got dates such as 26-Mar-16,19-Dec-16,..etc it would be grouped under 01-Jan-16

You would then include that column in the outer portion of the in-line views and group it as a field "txn_year" in the query as follows..

```
 SELECT txn_year,
        COUNT(DISTINCT INDIVIDUAL_ID),
        CASE WHEN COUNT_OF_TRANSACTIONS = 1 THEN '1'
             WHEN COUNT_OF_TRANSACTIONS = 2 THEN '2'
             WHEN COUNT_OF_TRANSACTIONS = 3 THEN '3'
             WHEN COUNT_OF_TRANSACTIONS = 4 THEN '4'
             WHEN COUNT_OF_TRANSACTIONS  >= 5 THEN '5+' 
         END AS TXN_TYPE,
         SUM(spend), 
         SUM(COUNT_OF_TRANSACTIONS)
    FROM (select  a.individual_id
                --Grouping by start of txn_year
                , trunc(txn_date,'YYYY') as txn_year
                , count(distinct transaction_number) as COUNT_OF_TRANSACTIONS
                , sum(a.dollar_value_us) as spend 
           from dm_owner.transaction_detail_mv a 
           join SL_NEWCUST2015HTRETCUST b 
             on a.individual_id = b.individual_id
          where brand_org_code = 'HT'
            and is_merch = 1
            and LINE_ITEM_AMT_TYPE_CD = 'S'
            and CURRENCY_CODE = 'USD'
            and a.individual_id is not null
            and COUNT_OF_TRANSACTIONS >= 5
            and TYPE_OF_CUSTOMER = 'Returning Customers'
            --and trunc(txn_date) between '01-JAN-16' AND '31-DEC-16'  ---- I have to change the years here everytime I run the query
            --Add condition for the range of years here
            and trunc(txn_date,'YYYY') >= '01-Jan-16'
            and trunc(txn_date,'YYYY') <= '01-Jan-19'
           group by a.individual_id
           ,        trunc(txn_date,'YYYY')
           )
GROUP BY txn_year,
         CASE WHEN COUNT_OF_TRANSACTIONS = 1 THEN '1'
              WHEN COUNT_OF_TRANSACTIONS = 2 THEN '2'
              WHEN COUNT_OF_TRANSACTIONS = 3 THEN '3'
              WHEN COUNT_OF_TRANSACTIONS = 4 THEN '4'
              WHEN COUNT_OF_TRANSACTIONS  >= 5 THEN '5+' END
ORDER BY 1 ASC,2 ASC;
```

Comment: shoudn't and trunc(txn_date,'YYYY') <= '01-Jan-19' be and trunc(txn_date,'YYYY') <= '31-Jan-19' ?

Comment: the trunc(<date>,'YYYY') sets the <date> to the start of that year. Check the output

Comment: welcome any feedback on this, its helps if you have benefited on the query or technique i provided

Comment: Its not giving me the correct output. so the purpose of the query is to see if the customers in 2015 (customers in the table) have shopped in 2016, 2017, 2018 and 2019. your query is just grouping the customers and not seeing if the same customers have purchased in the subsequent years.

Comment: have a look at the question you posted, and see if its different from what you are asking in the comment. You talked about how to optimize the running of the query form 2016 to 2019. I modified the query to get you all of the years data in one output which is what you were after when you posted?

Comment: yes, the question is correct, but if you see the query is trying to find the customers from the table SL_NEWCUST2015HTRETCUST and trying to see if those customers purchased in the subsequent years by joining it to the transactions table. and to see that I have to change the year date. so your solution is correct but not giving me the correct data